# How to merge two docx files using docx4j?

Tags: java, docx4j

I have two docx files which I want to merge and I have the following code in docx4j with some errors! Both the docx files are using for the purpose of track changes. So the output file should be have the details of both the docx files.

```
import java.io.File;    
import java.util.ArrayList;          
import java.util.List;             
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException;   
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.io.SaveToZipFile;     
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage;   
import com.plutext.merge.BlockRange;  
import com.plutext.merge.BlockRange.HfBehaviour;          
import com.plutext.merge.BlockRange.SectionBreakBefore;         
import com.plutext.merge.BlockRange.NumberingHandler;          
import com.plutext.merge.BlockRange.StyleHandler;        
import com.plutext.merge.DocumentBuilder;         
public class MergeWholeDocumentsUsingBlockRange                                                                                                                                
{
     public final static String DIR_IN = System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "/"; 
     public final static String DIR_OUT = System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "/"; 
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
     String[] files = {"table.docx", "Table1.docx"}; 
     List blockRanges = new ArrayList(); 
     for (int i=0 ; i< files.length; i++) { 
     BlockRange block = new BlockRange(WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new File(DIR_IN + files[i]))); 
        blockRanges.add( block ); 
        block.setStyleHandler(StyleHandler.RENAME_RETAIN);
        block.setNumberingHandler(NumberingHandler.ADD_NEW_LIST);
        block.setRestartPageNumbering(false);
        block.setHeaderBehaviour(HfBehaviour.DEFAULT);
        block.setFooterBehaviour(HfBehaviour.DEFAULT);
        block.setSectionBreakBefore(SectionBreakBefore.NEXT_PAGE);
    } 
        // Perform the actual merge 
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = new DocumentBuilder(); 
        WordprocessingMLPackage output = documentBuilder.buildOpenDocument(blockRanges); 
       // Save the result 
       SaveToZipFile saver = new SaveToZipFile(output); 
       saver.save(DIR_OUT+"OUT_MergeWholeDocumentsUsingBlockRange.docx"); 
       } 
    }
```

Comment: This code works just fine for small docx

Comment: Is that a paid version?

Comment: Yes it is a paid version

Comment: http://www.plutext.com/m/index.php/products